# Pumping water out of a truncated cone using integration.

Tags: calculus, integration

So the issue I'm stuck with, is that I can do a cone, but I have no idea where to start with a cone that is truncated.

I have a truncated cone that has a base with radius of 3 meters and a top with a radius of 4 meters It's height is 4 meters and I want to pump the water out of a pipe that expands 1 meter above the truncated cone. I need to calculate the work required to pump out all the water.

I did a cylinder earlier and a cone, but I just can't seem to figure out this truncated cone.

Any advice on where to start with a problem like this?

Comment: What is the problem?  Are you given the density of water?  If so, can you calculate the total mass of water contained in the tank?  Is the work not given by the change in potential energy?  Is the potential energy not given by $mgh$?

Comment: @Dr.MV I'm given that the density of water is  p = 1000 and the gravity is 9.8 My issue is that I want to use a triangle since it's a cone, but it's truncated. I'm not quite sure how to calculate the volume of a truncated cone.

Answer (score 1):

The tank is a truncated circular cone with a base of radius $r=3\,$m, a depth of $4\,$m and top radius of $r=4\,$m. Let $y$ denote the vertical distance from the bottom of the tank. Then $r=3+\frac{1}{4}y$ is the radius of the slice of water lying $y$ meters above the bottom of the tank.
    [image: Truncated Cone filled with water]
Think of that slice of water as being solid rather than liquid, as if it were frozen. The amount of work done in pumping the water to a height of $5\,$m above the base is the same as if one had to move all those frozen slices to that height.

The volume of each slice is $\pi r^2\,dy$ with $dy$ representing the thickness. The mass of the slice (in the mks system) is found by multiplying the density $\rho=1000\,$ kg/m$^3$ times the volume, so 
\begin{equation}
M=1000\pi r^2\,dy=1000\pi\left(3+\frac{1}{4}y\right)^2dy
\end{equation}

Each of these slices of water must be moved upward a distance of $D=5-y$ meters against a gravitational force of $g=9.8\,$m/sec$^2$ resulting in the work for the slice at $y$ being

\begin{equation}
W_y=9800\pi\left(3+\frac{1}{4}y\right)^2(5-y)\,dy
\end{equation}

The total work to remove all the slices of water between $y=0$ and $y=4$ is

\begin{equation}
W=\int_{0}^{4}9800\pi\left(3+\frac{1}{4}y\right)^2(5-y)\,dy
\end{equation}

The rest is routine since the integrand is simply a third degree polynomial. The units will be joules.

Comment: This is the correct answer. +1

Answer (score 0):

In this case, you need to realise that one can obtain a cone by simply revolving/rotating a linear curve about the x-axis (or y-axis). You can then use the following integral. In general, the volume given by rotating the function $f(x)$ over an interval $[a,b]$ is given by:

$V(x)=\pi \int_a^b f(x)^2 \ dx$.

Combined with having a look at the following picture, I am sure you can calculate the volume of your truncated cone. 
(from: http://www.nabla.hr/DIASurfXFig.gif)

[image]

Comment: The question is about work done, not volume.

Comment: The op is actually having trouble with the volume computation. This is the best answer in that regard. The physics to go from volume to energy has been correctly provided by @Dr. MV.  For work, we would need a flow rate.

Comment: I assumed the OP would be able to do the rest of the calculation after being provided how to calculate the volume.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you had a tank in the shape of an inverted cone with a height of $16$ and radius $4$ on the top surface. Suppose you had to pump water out of that tank, but stop pumping when the depth of water is $12.$

In this modified problem, you will have pumped the water out of a truncated cone of height $4$ with top radius $4$ and bottom radius $3.$ This is just like the problem you were given, except that when you stop pumping, the surface is made of water rather than the solid material of the tank.

Can you solve the modified problem?

Comment: @Dr.MV In these problems we seldom describe the shape of the pipe or the location of the pump, because all that really matters (in measuring the energy) is where a parcel of water starts (in the tank) and where it finishes (at the outlet of the pipe). Note that in order for the pump to pump "all" the water to the outlet, the pipe must either be of negligible volume, or it must start full of water and we must consider "all" the water in the tank to be just some quantity of water, not a particular set of molecules.

Comment: @Dr. MV no, neglecting some energy terms (and the dynamics of height variation, assuming tank open to atmosphere), work is related to the height difference between the surface of the tank and the discharge, as you have correctly answered